# Как заставить работать скрипт на скрытых блоках?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь поменять класс у родителя если дочериный блок не пуст.
Есть скрипт, в тесте все работает, класс у родителя удаляет и присваивает, но когда пытаюсь на сайте завести, он не работает.
У родителя внутри целое древо div-ов, тот что проверяется пуст или заполнент находиться в самой глубине древа, я использую .closest() чтобы обратиться непосредственно к родительскому блоку и тем самым удалить класс.

Как я уже говорил, на тесте все работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.fr-element').text()) {  
        $('.fr-element').closest('.infonext_block').removeClass('input_remove').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

```css
.input_remove {display:none}
.fr-element {padding:0 20px;height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infonext_block input_remove">
  <span>Заголовок</span>
 <div class="1">
  <div class="2">
   <div class="3">
       <div class="fr-element" contenteditable="true"><br/>3333</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

На сайте структура блоков добавляется автоматически со стороны CMS движка, когда в шаблоне вывожу textarea тегом, что в итоге, посмотрев в консоле браузера, я вижу целую разметку. В этой разметке находиться блок с классом **.fr-element**, который и проверяется заполнен или пуст, чтобы выполнить действие и удалить класс у родителя, как мы видим в примере.

Либо скрипт загружается первым чем древо блоков, что в итоге не срабатывает, либо что-то другое.

Скрин консоли:
[image: Скрин консоли]

Скрипт не хочет работать с этой цепочкой блоков, которая сформирована самим движком.
Если прописать те же блоки в шаблоне, и выводить самостоятельно для теста, все прекрасно работает, пример с теми же классами выше.

Как можно решить?
Прошу помощи!

**Сама разметка после преобразования документа:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.fr-element').text()) {  
        $('.fr-element').closest('.infonext_block').removeClass('input_remove').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

```css
.input_remove {display:none}
.fr-element {border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infonext_block input_remove">
         <span class="btn_prim icons-info-circled-alt">Нет полей для заполнения!</span>
          <span class="add_h5">Укажите недостающие ингредиенты:</span>
           <div class="text_primehanie">
             <div class="wseditor">
              <!--panel-->
               <div class="fr-box fr-ltr gray-theme fr-basic fr-top" role="application" style="width: 100%;">
               <div class="fr-toolbar gray-theme fr-ltr fr-desktop fr-top fr-basic" style="">
                    <div class="fr-wrapper show-placeholder" dir="ltr" style="height: 314px; overflow: auto;">

<!-- БЛОК КОТОРЫЙ ПРОВЕРЯЕМ -->
                   <div class="fr-element fr-view" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true" aria-disabled="false" style="min-height: 290px;" spellcheck="true"> 
                            ПРОВЕРКА ЭТОГО БЛОКА НА ПУСТОТУ, ЕСЛИ ЗАПОЛНЕН ТО УДАЛЯЕМ КЛАСС (input_remove)  У РОДИТЕЛЯ  (infonext_block)
                    <br>
                   </div>
<!-- END БЛОК КОТОРЫЙ ПРОВЕРЯЕМ -->

                     <span class="fr-placeholder" style="font-size: 14.4px; line-height: 21.6px; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 0px; padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 0px; text-align: start;">Впишите те игредиенты, которые нужно добавить к рецепту. Каждый новый ингредиент пишите с новой строки. НАПРИМЕР: Помидор - 1 шт, Мясо куриное - 200 гр и т.е.</span>
                      </div>
                         <span class="fr-counter" style="bottom: 2px; margin-right: 0px;">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <textarea name="xfield[zametka_admin]" id="xf_zametka_admin" class="wysiwygeditor" placeholder="Впишите те игредиенты, которые нужно добавить к рецепту. Каждый новый ингредиент пишите с новой строки. НАПРИМЕР: Помидор - 1 шт, Мясо куриное - 200 гр и т.е." style="display: none;"></textarea>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Исходный код сформированный при вставке в шаблон работает, класс удаляет и добавляет. Не могу понять почему, если не добавлять в шаблон сформированный код, и выводить тегом textarea, то не работает.
При выводе тегом текстовое поле, движок автоматом скрывает его на странице и формирует ввод текста через **div contenteditable**, что в итоге получаем громоздкий код со всем на свете.

---

Проблема была решена, я забыл сам скрипт вставить в основной документ, что в итоге он и не срабатывал.
Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте необходимую разметку после преобразования документа.

Comment: Если бы я знал как добавить необходимую разметку после преобразования документа, я бы сделал, но только на начальном этапе изучения javascript. Помогите реализовать правильную работу скрипта, а то я сума сойду. Читаю, учусь, пока не дошёл до такого уровня чтобы что-то писать сложное. Погодите пожалуйста!

Comment: открываете консоль в браузере. Выбираете необходимый блок, в котором содержатся изменённые данные (Только нужную часть возьмите) Нажимаете на элемент правой кнопкой и `copy element`. )

Comment: Добавил в тему вопроса. Надеюсь то что нужно?!

Comment: Да, это то. Единственное - в данном формате, как я вижу, всё работает.

Comment: А что может мешать его работе? Я уже нп знаю где копать...